# Trimming down a relation to a partial order

Tags: order-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Is there any general approach for trimming a reflexive relation to a partial order on a finite set?

In particular, given a relation *R* defined on a finite set, which is reflexive *xRx*, and for all x $\ne$ y, *xRy* or *yRx*, but not both; is there a minimal/optimal way to get to a partial order by deleting *(x,y)* pairs from the relation *R*?

Comment: You say "symmetric $xRx$", but this is reflexivity.

Comment: Thank you.  Fixed it.  Partial orders themselves can be ordered such that a maximal partial order with the desired property exists. But how to get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious that we can identify a reflexive relation $R\subset V\times V$ with a digraph $G=(V,E)$ where $E=R \setminus \{(x,x)\}_{x\in V}$ (more explicitly, there is an edge $x \rightarrow y$ whenever $xRy$ and $x\neq y$).

Now, [remove cycles minimally](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71987/find-the-minimum-number-of-links-to-remove-from-digraph-to-make-it-acyclic) to end up with a graph $G^\prime$. The corresponding relation $R^\prime$ is not a partial order yet, since it might not satisfy transitivity.

Make $G^{\prime\prime}$ by adding in all edges in order to satisfy transitivity (i.e., if there are edges $x_1 \rightarrow x_2$ and $x_2 \rightarrow x_3$, add the edge $x_1 \rightarrow x_3$). The corresponding relation $R^{\prime\prime}$ is what you are looking for.

(I recommend drawing some pictures to understand what I've said, assuming I've not made any mistakes).

Comment: well, because of the initial circumstance all pairs of distinct elements are in the relation one way xor the other.  So rather than deleting, if I flip the members of the minimal set of edges to be removed for "acyclicity", I achieve transitivity at the same time. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's even better! Out of curiosity, what is this for?

Comment: advection of a radioactive contaminant in a liquid flow - reconstructing the flow direction from individual points' time activity curves